# How to reference a member of outer query in a inner query?

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I would like to write this SQL query in JPA 2.1 Criteria API :

```
select * from t_question q
where
(select count(*) from t_question_tag tag 
   where 
       q.question_id  = tag.question_id
       AND tag.tag_id in (18, 1)
) = 2;
```

I can't figure out how to reference the outer question member in the inner query.

I'm currently at this point :

```
      CriteriaQuery<Question> cq = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Question.class);
Root<Question> questions = cq.from(Question.class);
cq.distinct(true);

  Subquery<Long> selectTags = cq.subquery(Long.class);
  Root<QuestionTag> qt = selectTags.from(QuestionTag.class);
  Join<QuestionTag, Question> qtJoin = qt.join("question");
  selectTags
    .select(criteriaBuilder.count(qtJoin))
    .where(
        qt.get("tag").in(filter.getTags())
        );
  cq.where(criteriaBuilder.and(insArray),
      criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.literal(filter.getTags().size()), selectTags));
```

But it creates a second Join. Sql result is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
FROM T_QUESTION question0_
WHERE 1                    =
  (SELECT COUNT(question3_.question_id)
  FROM T_QUESTION_TAG questionta2_
  INNER JOIN T_QUESTION question3_
  ON questionta2_.question_id=question3_.question_id
  WHERE questionta2_.tag_id IN (18));
```

Comment: In your second code fragment, what do `cq` stands for ? (please update code fragment accordingly)

Comment: And i don't know precisely how JPA works on that point, but it seems your `WHERE ... = 2` becomes `WHERE 1 = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect the subquery to be more like this

```
Subquery<Long> selectTags = cq.subquery(Long.class);
Root<QuestionTag> qt = selectTags.from(QuestionTag.class);
selectTags.select(criteriaBuilder.count(qt));
selectTags.where(
        criteriaBuilder.equal(questions.get("id"), qt.get("id")),
        qt.get("tag").in(filter.getTags())
        );
```

Use the candidate from the outer query ("questions") to refer to the outer query, and don't see why you did a join previously either. I've assumed that the field in "Question" and "Tag" are both called "id".